# Regex NullObject in Trigger if run from Dataloader else works fine

Tags: apex, trigger, regular-expressions, null-pointer

Fellow developers,

I have a call to an email validation function in my before insert in my trigger, which basically puts the email blank if its not valid (according to the regex)

```
public static String validEmailOrBlank(String email)
{
    String emailRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})';
    Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);

    Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);

    if (!emailMatcher.matches()) {
        email = '';
    }
    return email;
}
```

This works fine if I manually create a record (in this case it is a custom object) which empties the email field (which is just a regular text fieldtype, no email field type, this is intentional)
However, when I use the dataloader to mass import records, I get nullpointers

```
... execution of BeforeInsert
caused by: System.NullPointerException: Script-thrown exception
(System Code)
Class.Utilities.validEmailOrBlank: line 9, column 1
...
```

line 9 in this case is:

```
Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Not too novel approach but, can you try wrapping this in a try catch block
try{ 
Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);
}
catch(exception ex){
}
(or)
if(email.lenght()> 0 && email != ''){
    Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The csv file you're loading potentially contains null email addresses. (I was able to reproduce the NullPointerException by passing a null string to your method in Execute Anonymous, so a fair assumption I would think)

Your code, as it stands, would throw a null pointer exception if the email field is null.
So add a not null check for email before attempting to compile a pattern match

```
public static String validEmailOrBlank(String email)
{
if (email != null) { //NOT NULL CHECK
    String emailRegex = '([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.[a-z]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})';
    Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);

    Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);

    if (!emailMatcher.matches()) {
        email = '';
    }
   }
    return email;
}
```

Just tried this and it works alright.

Comment: @techtrkker email seems to be a string param !!!! Would it not be more accurate to check for the email != '' before it enters  the  line Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(email);

Comment: It doesn't really matter, if it is null you don't have to do much. I would even consider adding a not null check before invoking the method.

Comment: Also an empty string is not the same as a null string. An empty string i.e '' wouldn't cause a NullPointerException, only a null string does.

Comment: I feel such a tool, such a simple solution, however it was a combination of wrong mapping in the CSV (because all the emails were filled in), a long day at work, tunnelvision on the problem, and now its fixed, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Glad it helped. We can all do with a fresh pair of eyes on a long day! :)